# VBScript drag & drop with relative references

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript but have been doing as much research before asking the question. I have the script working that when a file is dropped on the icon it opens it up, runs a macro from another file in the same folder and then closes. What I am looking to do is to change it so the location of the macro is relative to the VBScript file, as it will be used in different locations.

```
Wscript.echo "Start analysis..." 
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\RT_Macro\macro")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(objArgs(0))
xlApp.Run "'macro.xlsm'!analysis"
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\RT_Macro\macro").Close
Wscript.echo "...Analysis complete"
```

I have tried using examples from others on this site using GetAbsolutePathname but keep getting errors that it cannot find the file and the directory is System32.
Any help to get it working or tidy up will be great.

Comment: `tried using examples from others on this site using GetAbsolutePathname` - where is your example code that failed? What is is the path of the vbscript file? You should be able to use the folder traversal methods (".." and ".") to find your path relative to the current one.

Comment: Can you parse `WScript.ScriptFullName` to get the path?